# Multi instance task execution

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have task:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "3000")
public void test() {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

And I want to have 3 instances of this task, I specified ThreadPoolTaskExecutor which has 3 pools, but I get 3 tasks which wait others execution, how can I run them parallel without waiting other tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I can think of right now (without digging deeper into the documentation) is to have your task scheduled once and it starts three threads.

First, you create a `ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);` and have this as a static variable.

In your `@Scheduled` method, you do the processing 3 times by calling `executor.submit()` 3 times with the same underlying method (you extract the actual processing part in a separate method).

Answer (score -1):

A good way is to use sprint async

```
@EnableAsync
public class ScheduledFixedRateExample {
    @Async
    @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = 3000)
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

}
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem the IP asked. It still does the processing once.